# JavaScript Telegram API

Tags: javascript, telegram

Нужна помощь с Telegram API, не могу найти нужную библиотеку для разработки на JavaScript.
Находил 3 варианта, но не смог разобраться в них.
Киньте, пожалуйста, рабочую библиотеку и хотя-бы 1 пример, как её использовать и выполнить какой-то API метод.
Я хочу создать HTML страничку с подключёнными к ней JS файлами и работать с API.